# Can I put the auto directory in my .gitignore for my Jekyll Bootstrap blog?

Tags: blogs, jekyll, gitignore, jekyll-bootstrap

So I am using [**Jekyll Bootstrap**](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/), which is also [**available on GitHub**](https://github.com/plusjade/jekyll-bootstrap), in order to build [**my blog**](http://coryg89.github.io) (which is currently just full of filler content for development). One thing I noticed is that when running my local development server using the command

```
$ jekyll --server --auto
```

I am able to edit my markdown content and have it auto regenerate the local site while I am changing things. As far as I can tell this does not work for my CSS or for my templates. I also noticed that when I run the local server with the `--auto` flag Jekyll creates a directory called `auto` which stores what appears to be a static copy of my site's content. Jekyll-bootstrap comes with it's own .gitignore file set up for you which I assumed contained the `auto` directory. I see no reason to store this auto-regenerated content in the [**GitHub repository for my site**](https://github.com/CoryG89/coryg89.github.com), however, when I made a commit I noticed it added the entire auto directory. I opened up the .gitignore file and this is what it contains:

```
_site/*
_theme_packages/*

Thumbs.db
.DS_Store

!.gitkeep

.rbenv-version
.rvmrc
```

I am very new to Jekyll and Jekyll Bootstrap, and a little new to git. I am not sure if there is a reason why they wouldn't have an entry to ignore the auto directory. I was figuring I should add an entry for `auto/*`. Is there a reason I shouldn't do this? As far as I can tell there is no use for the auto directory for anyone that either downloading the site from the web or from its git repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it in your gitignore file. When deploying your site, you'll generally build it into the `_site` directory and publish it somewhere (your own VPS, GitHub pages, etc).